# Entirely new git repo says "Everything up-to-date" when trying to push to entirely new remote

Tags: git, push

I am a git newbie. I just created a new project with just 4 new files test1 test2 test3 test4. Then all I did are the following:

```
$ git init
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "VERY 1st commit"
```

as simple as that.

then i added a remote repo is also an entirely new repo i just created in bitbucket.org

```
$ git remote add rakspace http://syedrakib@bitbucket.org/syedrakib/mysamplegit
$ git push rakspace
```

as you can tell it's entirely new workspace being pushed into an entirely new repo. it returns this:

> Everything up-to-date

what is it i am doing wrong here? Clearly the source files of the remote repo are NOT getting updated.

EDIT: I have got 2 branches in my local repo: ***master*** and ***new_branch***

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default behavior of `git push` is to push "matching" branches. That means any branches on your side that have a branch named the same thing on the other side get pushed. In a brand new repository, there are no branches. Therefore no branches match. You can cause a branch with a name matching your branch to be created on the remote using `git push <remote name> <branch name>`. In your case: `git push rakspace master`

You can find out about and change the push settings by looking for `push.default` in the [git config documentation](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/git-config.1.html).

Comment: Hi Ryan, i tried `git push rakspace master`... it still says `Everything up-to-date`. Is it because there is no matching branch name called `master` in the remote repo?

Comment: If you did that, then it means everything is up to date. End of story. I.e. you have no commits in your master branch that aren't already in the remote master branch.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing `git push rakspace master`.  Think you need to specify which branch you want to push.

If that's not the problem then, I'm wondering if you actually added anything to the repository by doing `git add .`?

Try doing

```
touch TEST
git add .
git commit -m "Committing a file named TEST."
git push rakspace master
```

Comment: Hi Batkins, i tried `git push rakspace master`... it still says `Everything up-to-date`. Is it because there is no matching branch name called `master` in the remote repo?

Comment: i did do `git add .` several times.... in fact i did some minor changes several times and committed several times.... no luck

Comment: Ok just wasn't certain that you actually had some files to commit.  Can you try running `git push rakspace -u master`?  The `-u` option sets the local branch to track the remote branch.

Comment: To clarify, when I said remote branch, I meant remote master branch.  Every repository has at least one branch (the master branch for that repository).  If you run `git branch`, it should print out `master`, which is your master branch.

Comment: okay.... i understood. well i tried that. surprisingly even that is `Everything Up-To-Date` ... aaaarrrgghh.

Comment: What do you see if you do a `git log`?  Did it actually register your commits on your side?  Is there any way to connect to the server with ssh and run `git log` on that end to see if the commits are registered there?   Also what is the output you see if you run `git remote show rakspace`?

Comment: how funny..... i just did `git push rakspace --all` and it worked. Now i can push and pull like normal.

Comment: Huh.  Interesting... Sounds like you may have had more than one branch on one of your repos... what happens when you type git branch?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4399/discussion-between-syedrakib-and-batkins)

Answer (score 0):

After tonnes of discussions in multiple places all over the web, i figure the solution for first time push to a clean new repo is

```
git push rakspace --all
```

From then on, the push-pull are working like normal. HOW FUNNY??!!!

Comment: It's not correct to say that your first operation with a new remote repo must be a `push --all`. You indicated in your conversation with Batkins that you had multiple branches at some time in the past, implying that your repos weren't actually as pristine as your question indicated. With two truly new repos, all that's required is `git push <remote name> <branch name>` to push a branch.

Comment: i have updated my question with the fact about 2 branches in my local repo.... thanks for correcting me there @RyanStewart .

Comment: so, does `git push rakspace --all` push in **ALL** my branches into the remote repo?

Comment: Yes, the `--all` option tells git to push all of your local branches without having to list them.